# Get name of error attributes from Respect/Validation

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I'm using Respect validation library and when I try to validate my input date:

```
v::key('email', v::notEmpty()->Email()->setName('email'))
```

It returns the right message like:

```
"email must be valid email"
```

But I cannot retrieve name of the attribute which makes the error happen, I hope it has some function like getErrorName() or getErrorAttributes but I cannot find it out. Could you please help me.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this lengthy discussion with the developers for 3 years regarding this very issue. It may not be possible to do what you ask using this validation library.

https://github.com/Respect/Validation/issues/86

Comment: Is there any difference if I don't use OOP?
As I see, you change the messages, but I just want to receive the name of the attributes like "username" or "email" or "password" which causes the error.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue resolved, i changed my answer.